# How to make a function accessible to a specific platform?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I'm creating a class that has functions that do similar tasks but one is using API's only available on that platform. Is it possible to make it so the function is not accessible when building for a specific platform?

Example:

```
class myClass {

    // How can I hide this function when I'm building for macOS?
    class func myFunctionForIOS() {

    }
    // And hide this when building for iOS?
    class func myFunctionForMACOS() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has [Preprocessor Directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31) that can do this:

```
func myFunction() {
  #if os(macOS)
    // do something
  #elseif os(iOS)
    // do something else
  #else
    // do a final thing
  #endif
}
```

A bit more info [here too](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassA{
  //define common method
  virtual void MethodA() = 0;
}

class ClassA_iOS_Impl: public ClassA{
  //override your implement for iOS
  void MethodA() override {//call iOS specific API}
}

class ClassA_Mac_Impl: public ClassA{
  //override your implement for Mac
  void MethodA() override {//call Mac specific API}
}
```

then build different files based on your platform.

Comment: This is also a good way to go about it, it trades locality of a customization for modularity. There are arguments to be had for both preprocessor directives and virtual methods.